# How to access methods in java from other methods?

Tags: java, methods

I'm very new to programming. However, I've written a method called "succ" that's adds 1 to a given parameter. It looks like this:

```
int succ(int x) {
  return x += 1;
}
```

Now I'm supposed to write another method that adds 2 numbers using my first method. This is what my attempt looks like:

```
int add(int x, int y) {
  for(int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    succ(x);
  }
  return x;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work; it always returns the initial x. For example: If I type add(8,5) it just returns 8. Can someone help me? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try doing `x = succ(x)` . Also, read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1

Comment: Oh wow, it worked. I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to programming!! You're really going good. As answer is also posted would recommend you to refer [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?rq=1)

Comment: @Shashwat has the fix and I would change your `succ(int x)` to `succ(int somethingelse)` just for readability. It's easy to get confused starting out.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything with the returned value.  If you want to assign it back to `x`, do that:

```
x = succ(x);
```

**Edit:** Or, perhaps you mean to *add* to `x`, since you're doing it in a loop?  It's not *entirely* clear what this code is meant to do, and I suspect more applicable variable/method names would help.  But if you want to keep adding the result, you'd just do this:

```
x += succ(x);
```

Additionally, you don't need to modify `x` in your `succ` function.  Doing so in this manner may lead to unexpected behavior in the future in other examples.  Keep the operations as simple as possible.  Just return the calculated value:

```
return x + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the solution. Also thanks for the advice about modifying `x` in my `succ` function!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return value of the **succ** method, replace the   `succ(x);` with  `x = succ(x);`

```
int add(int x, int y) {

  for(int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
    x = succ(x);
  }
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep overwriting the x value with the return value from the function.  You need to add to it in each iteration, not overwrite it.